# Markdown. What are inline and reference style links?

Tags: markdown

I've been using markdown recently and there is one thing I just can't understand: what is the difference between inline and reference style links? I've looked into some guides, but they only show the syntax for each.

So why or when should I use one style over the other?

Comment: *"they only show the syntax for each"* - that **is** the only difference. Use whichever you think makes your raw Markdown more readable; the rendered result will be identical.

Comment: See the last two paragraphs of the [links section](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) of the original syntax rules. That explains the original creator's intent.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That is *not* the only difference.  URL's can be extremely long, and may need to be *referenced* in more than one place.  By placing the URL as a *reference* and *referring to it* in a link, **you can be sure any additional links referring to it get the same URL**, even if you change the URL.

Because you only need to change the URL in the reference, and links that refer to it will benefit from that same change, all at once and the same.

Answer (score 6):

The point of reference-style links is not that they’re easier to write. The point is that with reference-style links, your document source is vastly more readable.

https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link